# add column to query in reverse order

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
select time, a, b, c from table order by time asc

time  a  b  c
1     x  x  x
2     y  y  y
3     z  z  z
```

I want to add column time additionally to the query in reverse order. The original query should keep the same structure and order.

```
select time, time_reverse, a, b, c from table order by time asc

time  a  b  c  time_reverse
1     x  x  x  3
2     y  y  y  2
3     z  z  z  1
```

Sorry, I tried several things and used google but cannot find this, maybe easy solution.

Comment: An example please

Comment: this seems so simple that an example will not deliver any additional value but here we go

Comment: You think? I think question needs clarification

Comment: is it now clear?

Comment: It is much clearer. Thank you.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Not a time value at all then and yes much clearer

Comment: ----> Version 8.0.19

Comment: time should represent unixtime but it will not make any difference for the order problem I guess

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions to add a row_number to the result set and then joining that back upon itself may work here:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `time`) as rn, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY `time` DESC) as rn2
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT cte.time, cte.a, cte.b, cte.c, cte2.time
FROM cte INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte.rn = cte.rn2
ORDER BY cte.time;
```

`rn` and `rn2` are just row numbers where one is the reverse numbering of the other. Joining on that should give you the output you are after.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using window function (since MySQL 8.0). 
You need to join two queries with different order by row_number() value:

```
select 
    table.*, 
    reverted.time as reverted_time
from
(
    select 
        time, a, b, c, row_number() over (order by time asc) rownum
    from table
) table
join (
    select 
        time, row_number() over (order by time desc) rownum 
    from table 
) reverted on reverted.rownum = table.rownum;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a717ab4315a3d755b3c444a10831fde5)